# Load more cells when user scrolls to bottom of tableview frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am adding new data to a `tableView` when the user scrolls to bottom like this....

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
        float  height = self.itemListTableView.frame.size.height;
        float contentYoffset = aScrollView.contentOffset.y;
        float distanceFromBottom = aScrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset;
        if (distanceFromBottom < height) {
        NSLog(@" you reached end of the table");
        isTableScrolledToBottom = YES;
   }else{
        isTableScrolledToBottom = NO;
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    ListViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if(cell==nil){
      cell = [[ListViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }
       //Assign values to labels here..

    if (isTableScrolledToBottom) {

        if (indexPath.row == [apiMutableArray count]-1)
        {
            // Call the API
            NSLog(@"Call the api");
            int pgn = [self.currentPageNumber intValue];
            pgn = pgn+1;
            self.currentPageNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:pgn];
            NSLog(@"incremented page number : %@",self.currentPageNumber);
            NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [self.poPostDict mutableCopy];
            [mutableDict setObject:self.currentPageNumber forKey:@"pageno"];
            self.poPostDict = [mutableDict mutableCopy];

            [self addLoaderViewAtBottom];
            [self loadPOData:self.poPostDict]; 
        }
    }
 return cell;
}
```

Now if the data in table view is big enough, the user will scroll to bottom and data fetching is done from api as expected.However when I filter this table and lets say I get only one row of data.
In such case even if I can see only one cell is present in the table, if I try to scroll the table, the api request is hit.
How to actually know if user has scrolled beyond its `frame` and upto `scrollView's` end so that only in that case I can fetch the data.

Note:- Using current technique if only one row is present and I try to scroll, the api call is hit continuously without stopping.

Comment: Solution is already present on stack. Have you tried any one?

Comment: I have found these techniques on stack itself.However if I filter the  table the solutions don't seem to work.

Comment: You don't need to filter the data you have to add data.

Comment: 'Filter' option is one of the options present in the app.If the users filters the data based on some criteria of his/her liking, the data source is reduced.Now if I get only 2-3 elements and I try to scroll the table.The api request is hit as I am scrolling to end here.

Comment: You need to add new data after load more to the old data.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution, it always work for me.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let lastElement = dataSource.count - 1
        if indexPath.row == lastElement {
            // logic here
            }    
    }
```

If you still have doubt then ask.

Comment: i need help regarding the same issue, i have a JSON response of image and it has 193 data as of now it can be increased in future so currently i want to display only 20 cells at one time and when user reaches at 20th cells and scrolls i want to show another 20 cells below so that image loading will be faster . i want like facebook pagination, i donot want to add pagecount to increment and fetch the value when i call delegate methods.thnks in advance... this is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187395/how-to-show-cells-based-on-increment-of-array-in-tableview-swift-3

Comment: check bro now Is it ok for u

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166574/discussion-between-dilip-tiwari-and-dahiya-boy).